# Why is $((n-1) \mod 9)+1$ equal to summing all digits till one digit is left?

Tags: summation

There was a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37279251/excel-formula-that-use-while-to-get-a-1-digit-number) on SO on how to, in excel, sum all digits in a number until you are left with one single digit. The correct answer, in excel format, turns out to be `=1+MOD(A1-1,9)` which I wrote as $((n-1) \mod 9)+1$. I tried this it out with several numbers,

- `n=123` : $1+2+3 = 6$ and $((123-1) \mod 9)+1 = 6$
- `n=456` : $4+5+6 = 15, 1+5 = 6$ and $((465-1) \mod 9)+1 = 6$
- `n=8910` : $8+9+10 = 27, 2+7 = 9$ and $((8910-1) \mod 9)+1 = 9$

Now I try to understand the relationship between summing all the numbers and simply using the formula $((n-1) \mod 9)+1$. Why are these two always equal?

Comment: Note that $10\equiv 1 \pmod 9$.  What does this say about, say, $8*10^3+9*10^2+1*10^1+0\pmod{9}?  $

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sum of the digits in any number is congruent to that number modulo $9$. To see why it holds write the number $\overline{z...cba}$, as $a\cdot10^0 + b\cdot 10^1 +...$ and use the fact that the $10 \equiv 1 \pmod 9$. Repeating this step will not change the remainder modulo 9, so eventually we will get a number between $1$ and $9$, as $0$ is impossible.

On the other hand we get that $((n-1) \mod 9) + 1$ gives us the remainder of $n$ when divided by $9$. The trick when we first subtract $1$ and add it at the end ensures that we'll get a number between $1$ and $9$, rather than in the congruence class of $9$, which is from $0$ to $8$. In other words you calculate the remainder of $n-1$ modulo 9 and then you just add $1$ as the remainders between $n$ and $n-1$ differ by 1.

Comment: Once again I have problems with English syntax and I take long to write a solution. I wanted generalize to subtract not only $1$ but also any digit and comes out the same. And I suspect it may even be replaced $1$ by any other integer not only the first 8 digits.

Comment: @Piquito if we replace 1 by any other integer than the formula will output numbers of the set $\{k,k+1,...,k+8\}$, which is not necessarily a one digit number. Actually we can see that only $k=1$ works

Comment: Hi Stefan: Look at this:(1) $439\to 439-5=434=48\cdot 9+2\to 2+5=7$. Now $4+3+9=16\to 1+6=7$. 

(2) $747\to747-8=739=82\cdot 9 +1\to 1+8=9$. Now $7+4+7=18\to 1+8=9$.

 You can verify the question with other values. Regards.

Comment: @Piquito what about 39? We have $39 \to 3+9 = 12 \to 1+2 = 3$. On the other hand $((39-5) \mod 9) + 5 = 7 + 5 = 12$, but the results are different. Obviously they are congruent modulo 9 always, but this defeats the purpose of subtracting 1 at the beginning and adding it later, as we want to get the same number, not number that are congruent mod 9, but not necessarily same

Comment: I understand now what you say. However the residue must be of one digit and $1+2=3$. For a generalization it remains an easy additional detail. Finally let's get this. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Piquito if we sum the digits until we get a digit then yes all integer serve the purpose. But as I've said the this becomes trivial, as what we do is similar to concluding that (2-1) + 1 is equal to 2

Answer (score 0):

**(I saw this topic a long time ago, the formula needs to be proven.
I use Google Translate from Vietnamese.)**

Prove that the formula $P_{(s)} = (s - 1) \mod 9 + 1$ finds the sum of one digit of an integer greater than 0 with one or more digits.

## Prove:

- Let $A$ be the set of integers **{$1,2,...,9$}**.
- Let $P_{(s)}$ be the sum of one digit of a multi-digit number.
- Based on the formula $P_{(s)} = (s - 1) \mod 9 + 1$, $s > 0$, then $s - 1$ is always $s \ge 0$, so $P_{(s)} € A$.
- Let $a1, a2, a3, ..., an$ be the digits in a number, the value of the set {$0,1,2,...,9$}.
- Let $s$ be a 1 or more digit number.

Me has the general formula of $s$:

\begin{align}
s & = a1*10^0 + a2*10^1 + a3*10^2 + ... + an*10^{n-1}\\
& = a1 + a2*10 + a3*10^2 + ... + an*10^{n-1}\\
& =  a1 + a2 + a2*(10^1-1) + a3 + a3*(10^2-1) + ... + an + an*(10^{n-1}-1 )\\
& = a1 + a2 + a3 + ... + an + a2*9 + a3*99 + ... + an*(10^{n-1}-1 )\\
\end{align}

Let **b** be the value of the expression $a2*9 + a3*99 + ... + an*(10^{n-1}-1)$, based on the sign of divisibility by 9, **b** is always divisible by 9.

Let $C_{n}$ be the sum of n numbers, the values ​​obtained are respectively:

| $C_{n}$ | total value | values |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $C_{1}$ | a1 | $0 \to 1*10-1 = 9*1$ |
| $C_{2}$ | a1 + a2 | $0 \to 2*10-2 = 9*2$ |
| $C_{3}$ | a1 + a2 + a3 | $0 \to 3*10-3 = 9*3$ |
| $C_{n}$ | a1 + a2 + a3 + ... + an | $0 \to n*10-n = 9*n$ |

\begin{align}
Cₙ & = a1 + a2 + a3 + ... + an\\
& = a1 + a2*10 + a3*10^2 + ... + an*10^{n-1} - a2*9 - a3*99 - ... - an*(10^{n-1}-1)\\
& =  s - b\\
\end{align}

### Conclusion **[1]** :

- when **s** loses **b** value, we get a sum of digits
- **[2]** When n = 1, then $C_{n}$ € A , $s = C_{n}$, $P_{(s)} = (s - 1) \mod 9 + 1$ is always true.

### With **s**:

\begin{align}
s & = C_{n} + b\\
& = (C_{n})_{C_{n}} + b_{C_{n}} + b​\\
& = ((C_{n})_{C_{n}})_{C_{n}} + b_{(C_{n})_{C_{n}}} + b_{C_{n}} + b​\\
& = ...((C_{n})_{C_{n}})_{C_{n}} + b...((C_{n})_{C_{n}})_{C_{n}} + ... + b_{(C_{n})_{C_{n}}} + b_{C_{n}} + b​\\
\end{align}

Let $Z_{m}$ be the sum of $C_{n}$ the expression of the value **s**, to get **[3]** the value $Z_{m} € A$ then:
\begin{align}
s = b + bZ_{0} + bZ_{1} + bZ_{2} + ... + bZ_{m-1} + Z_{m}\\
\end{align}
Let **B** be the value of the expression $b + bZ_{0} + bZ_{1} + bZ_{2} + ... + bZ_{m-1}$ then:
$$s = Z_{m} + B​$$

### Based on **[1]** :

\begin{align}
P_{(s)} & = Z_{m} + B - B\\
& = Z_{m} + B \mod 9​\\
\end{align}

### Based on [2] and [3] :

\begin{align}
P_{(s)} & = (Z_{m}-1) \mod 9 + 1 + B \mod 9​\\
& = (Z_{m} + B - 1) \mod 9 + 1​\\
& = (s - 1) \mod 9 + 1​\\
\end{align}

### Conclusion Thesis:

The formula $P_{(s)} = (s - 1) \mod 9 + 1$ finds the sum of one digit of an integer greater than 0 with one or more digits.

Comment: Your formulas aren't rendering tight and are unreadable. Please format your math with MathJax. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).